# 3 inputs 5 outputs. Creating new columns on existing data

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, datagridview

I have input: bruto, a/p %, t/a%:

Example:

- bruto | a/p% | t/a% |
- 100 | 50 | 25  |

Output I want:

- bruto | a/p% | Neto | t/a% | total |
- 100 | 50 | formula:100/100*a/p%=50 | 25 | Formula:50/100*t/a%=12,5 |

My code query for the moment. Work for creating:

```
Bruto | a/p% | Neto | and then syntax errors

tabula22.Load(new SqlCommand("SELECT     dbo.produkti_items_tab.itemname AS [Produkta nosaukums], dbo.tehnkart_produkt_tab.bruto AS [Bruto sv.], dbo.tehnkart_produkt_tab.aukstie_zudumi_proc AS [Zudumi % a/p],CAST((dbo.tehnkart_produkt_tab.bruto / 100 *


dbo.tehnkart_produkt_tab.aukstie_zudumi_proc) AS numeric(10,2)) 'Neto sv. gr.', dbo.tehnkart_produkt_tab.karstie_zudumi_proc AS [Zudumi % t/a], CAST((dbo.[Neto sv. gr.] / 100 * dbo.[Zudumi % t/a]) AS numeric(10,2)) 'beka', CAST(([Bruto sv.]-[Neto sv. gr.]-[beka]) AS numeric(10,2)) 'Total'   
FROM dbo.tehnkart_produkt_tab INNER JOIN dbo.produkti_items_tab ON dbo.tehnkart_produkt_tab.item_id = dbo.produkti_items_tab.itemid WHERE (dbo.tehnkart_produkt_tab.kart_id = '" + dat1_id + "')", TestConnection).ExecuteReader());
```

p.s hard edit here =]

Comment: What's the error message? And can you please edit your question so that your command appears on multiple lines so it's easier to read? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are attempting to reference column aliases multiple times. You have to either wrap your current query in a subquery to use the column definitions multiple times:

```
string mySql = @"
SELECT [Produkta nosaukums],
    [Bruto sv.],
    [Zudumi % a/p],
    [Neto sv. gr.],
    [Zudumi % t/a],
    CAST(([Neto sv. gr.] / 100 * [Zudumi % t/a]) AS numeric(10,2)) [beka],
    CAST(([Bruto sv.]-[Neto sv. gr.]-(CAST(([Neto sv. gr.] / 100 * [Zudumi % t/a]) AS numeric(10,2)))) AS numeric(10,2)) [Total]
FROM
(
    SELECT dbo.produkti_items_tab.itemname AS [Produkta nosaukums], 
        dbo.tehnkart_produkt_tab.bruto AS [Bruto sv.], 
        dbo.tehnkart_produkt_tab.aukstie_zudumi_proc AS [Zudumi % a/p],
        CAST((dbo.tehnkart_produkt_tab.bruto / 100 * dbo.tehnkart_produkt_tab.aukstie_zudumi_proc) AS numeric(10,2)) [Neto sv. gr.], 
        dbo.tehnkart_produkt_tab.karstie_zudumi_proc AS [Zudumi % t/a] 
    FROM dbo.tehnkart_produkt_tab 
    INNER JOIN dbo.produkti_items_tab 
        ON dbo.tehnkart_produkt_tab.item_id = dbo.produkti_items_tab.itemid 
    WHERE dbo.tehnkart_produkt_tab.kart_id = '" + dat1_id + @"'
) d";
tabula22.Load(new SqlCommand(mySql, TestConnection).ExecuteReader());
```

Comment: At the end code "d" what it is ?//

Comment: @user2182959 That is the alias for the subquery. SQL Server requires an alias on all derived tables and subqueries.

Comment: have you added sql comment `--` prior to the WHERE in the subquery on purpose?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss no, I didn't mean that.  removed

Comment: Do you mind IF I edit your answer to use c# @ string to keep this format?

Comment: Nice you code work, can you just LAST help me :), how correct put this query in my c# code, for multilines, because all my querys at the moment one big LINE.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Go ahead. :)

Comment: Can you put your query here plz c# code.
`tabula22.Load(new SqlCommand("PuTHEREquerry", TestConnection).ExecuteReader());`

Comment: Mark Schultheiss - you can edit my question

Comment: @user2182959 - probably need to make that SQL parameterized instead of inline sql for that id. - what version of c#/.net?

Comment: Hmm i found small BUG, i think problem in formula:
bruto:100,a/p%0, then Neto need be 100, because no lose if 0. Hmm need to read more math :)

Comment: Now trying add this formula here :) x - (x * (% * 0.01))